# add total bytes in iptables

Tags: bash, sum, iptables

how can I add grep output number line by line.

I have the below output file from

```
     pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.117
       0        0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.0.1          0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.1
  375993 19581223 RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.1.136        0.0.0.0/0
  752537 1043650417 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.136
     123     9348 RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.1.100        0.0.0.0/0
     121     9196 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.100
```

I want to add all bytes for each IP address and store it as variable for further calculation.

```
iptables -L RRDIPT -vnx -t filter | grep "192.168.1" | cut -d " " -f4
```

gives me the blanks and 19581223,1043650417,9348  and 9196  but I am struggling to add the output.

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following script tallies up the byte counts per *destination IP*. If you want per *source IP* then change the `$9` to `$8`

```
iptables -L ... | awk '!/destination/{a[$9]+=$2}END{for(item in a)printf("%s\tTotal bytes: %s\n",item,a[item])}'
```

#### Input

```
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   0        1 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.117
   0        2 RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.0.1          0.0.0.0/0
   0        3 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.1
   0        4 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.117
   0        5 RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.0.1          0.0.0.0/0
   0        6 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.117
   0        7 RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.0.1          0.0.0.0/0
```

#### Output

```
192.168.0.1     Total bytes: 3
0.0.0.0/0       Total bytes: 14
192.168.1.117   Total bytes: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

[`awk`](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/27740-adding-contents-file.html) will make short work of that.