# awk array output

Tags: arrays, awk

i have an ip list array

```
ip_array=['192.168.1.100' '192.168.1.101' '192.168.1.102' '192.168.1.103' '192.168.1.104' '192.168.1.105' '192.168.1.106' '192.168.1.107' '192.168.1.108' '192.168.1.109' '192.168.1.110']
```

i want to run iptables output against the ip_array and get results. 
e.g

```
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   83276  4337105   RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.1.106        0.0.0.0/0
  166008 230477883  RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.106
       0        0   RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.1.107        0.0.0.0/0
       0        0   RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.107
       0        0   RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.1.103        0.0.0.0/0
       0        0   RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.103
      99     9144   RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.1.102        0.0.0.0/0
      79    11590   RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.102
       0        0   RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.1.101        0.0.0.0/0
       0        0   RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.101
  994874 51992106   RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.1.100        0.0.0.0/0
 2398169 3594009427 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.100
       0        0   RETURN     0    --  *      *       192.168.1.106        0.0.0.0/0
       0        0   RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.106
```

from my previous post I learnt that I can get the bytes info using awk

```
iptables -L RRDIPT -vnx -t filter |awk '!/destination/{a[$9]+=$2}END{for(item in a){total+=a[item];dl[item]=a[item];printf item"-"a[item]}}'
```

but since the ip address keep changing i want my output to be in the same format..

```
i.e bytesof 192.168.1.100, bytesof 192.168.1.102, bytesof 192.168.1.103, bytesof 192.168.1.104.......bytesof 192.168.1.110
```

i would like to see the below output

```
[3594009427,0,11590,0,0,0,230477883,0,0,0,0]
```

I tried using arrays

```
iptables -L RRDIPT -vnx -t filter |awk '!/destination/{a[$9]+=$2}END{for(item in a){if(item==ip_array[i]){dl[i]=a[item];printf dl[i];}else{dl[i]=0}i+=i;}}'
```

I declared `dl` as a global array but I cannot seem to access the values e.g `dl[0]` for further processing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I am scared to format the question :P

Comment: i am scared too, to format the question

Comment: I am brave enough ;) - but now someone else answer it ;)

Comment: I'll answer it if the OP puts sample output of what he is looking for.

Comment: oops.. apologies people, n00b to stackoverflow. SiegeX i am looking for a structured output i.e, i want to get the bytes of the ip address that are active.if the ip address is not active i need to return 0. for the above iptables output i would like to see the below output
3594009427,0,11590,0,0,0,230477883,0,0,0,0
i.e bytesof 192.168.1.100, bytesof 192.168.1.102, bytesof 192.168.1.103, bytesof 192.168.1.104.......bytesof 192.168.1.110

Comment: Where is `ip_array` defined (populated)?

Comment: hi, i have declared ip_array as a staic array with 10 elements(ip address)

Comment: Hi Dennis, i have declared array as ip_array=('192.168.1.100' '192.168.1.101' '192.168.1.102' '192.168.1.103' '192.168.1.104' '192.168.1.105' '192.168.1.106' '192.168.1.107' '192.168.1.108' '192.168.1.109' '192.168.1.110')

Comment: **Where?** This is the third time I have asked "Where"? In a Bash script? Does that script wrap the command sequence shown in your question? Is this a fixed array or are you deriving it somehow? Bash arrays aren't available inside AWK scripts. It might be possible to awkwardly (no pun intended) pass them into the AWK script. Why don't you parse the IP addresses and total the byte counts dynamically at the same time? What are you going to do with these values? Further processing? Output to the screen? Something else? Please address comments using @Dennis so I'm automatically notified.

Comment: @Dennis my main objective is to get the bytes values for each ip address from the output of iptables -L, and graph the values.so i need to have the output from bash in the same order all the time i.e regardless of the ip address is active or not i need to have a value (0 if not present).
my intent is to store the ip address into array in the main bash script and use it in awk.can this be done? can you please suggest an efficient way? thanks

Comment: What does the data need to look like in its final form for the next step (i.e. graphing?)? [SiegeX's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664294/add-total-bytes-in-iptables) shows one way to output the IP addresses and the totals. It would be very simple to modify that output using the existing script from that answer so that it fits your requirements.

Comment: @Dennis final data output should be in the below format [1,2,3,0,5,6,7,8,0,10] i.e [bytesof ip address 192.168.1.100,bytesof ip address 192.168.1.101,bytesof ip address 192.168.1.102....................bytesof ip address 192.168.1.110] SiegeX answer gives only the active IP address bytes, i need an if else condition statement to have the same structured output i.e first value always be that of 192.168.1.100, 2nd values always be of 192.168.1.101....10th element always be of 192.168.1.110.. hope i am clear...thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
iptables ... | awk 'BEGIN { base="192.168.1"; startrange=100; endrange=110 } NR > 1 { a[$9] += $2} END {for (i=startrange; i<=endrange; i++) {ip = base "." i; if (! a[ip]) a[ip] = 0; print ip, a[ip]}}'
```

Change the `startrange` and `endrange` values to suit you.

Example output:

```
192.168.1.100 9196
192.168.1.101 0
192.168.1.102 0
192.168.1.103 0
192.168.1.104 21009126
192.168.1.105 0
192.168.1.106 0
192.168.1.107 10333
192.168.1.108 0
192.168.1.109 0
192.168.1.110 120
```

Comment: @user: I'm glad it was helpful. Don't forget to mark answers to your questions as accepted (when they are acceptable).